# Can I deploy a .NET Core Website on a server without dotnet?

Tags: .net-core, web-deployment, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm building a simple web application for a client that allows internal users upload files to specific directories on the server. I want to build an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application to do this.
However, when I got access to the server I ran

```
dotnet --version
```

And it does not return anything. Looking through the registry it seems like .NET Framework is installed.

I am a fairly new .NET developer. My questions are:

- is it possible to have .NET Framework installed and not .NET?
- can I deploy an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app on the server WITHOUT .NET?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to have .NET Framework installed and not .NET?

As far as I know, the dotnet --version is used to check the asp.net core SDK and runtime version.

If there is no response that means the server doesn't install the asp.net core runtime or else.

> can I deploy an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app on the server WITHOUT .NET?

If you don't use IIS to host your asp.net core application, you could deploy your asp.net core web application as self-host which is no need to install the dotnet runtime.

If you want to host it on the IIS, you must install the dotnet core runtime.